# py2exe doesn't work with pysnmp 4.3.0

Tags: py2exe, pysnmp

I use python 2.7.8.
I convert this code to an exe using py2exe:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore import *
def cbFun(snmpEngine, sendRequestHandle, errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds, cbCtx):
    print(errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds)
snmpEngine = SnmpEngine()
getCmd(snmpEngine,
       CommunityData('public'),
       UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0)),
       cbFun=cbFun)
snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
```

But every time I run the exe I get the following error:

```
could not get source code
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Maprinter.py", line 11, in <module>
File "pysnmp\entity\rfc3413\oneliner\cmdgen.pyc", line 124, in nextCmd
File "pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\cmdgen.pyc", line 337, in nextCmd
File "pysnmp\hlapi\varbinds.pyc", line 30, in makeVarBinds
File "pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.pyc", line 707, in resolveWithMib
File "pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.pyc", line 302, in resolveWithMib
File "pysnmp\smi\compiler.pyc", line 42, in addMibCompiler
File "pysmi\parser\smi.pyc", line 21, in __init__
File "pysmi\lexer\smi.pyc", line 83, in __init__
File "pysmi\lexer\smi.pyc", line 100, in reset
File "ply\lex.pyc", line 906, in lex
File "ply\lex.pyc", line 580, in validate_all
File "ply\lex.pyc", line 822, in validate_rules
File "ply\lex.pyc", line 833, in validate_module
File "inspect.pyc", line 690, in getsourcelines
File "inspect.pyc", line 538, in findsource
IOError: could not get source code
```

what should I do too solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to the "inspect" module behavior, not to pysnmp. There is a [ticket](http://bugs.python.org/issue15931) on similar problem. Although it was rejected.

Consider trying not to change current working directory once you start importing things, then relative paths may keep working.

This issue may not show up in Python 2.6- and 3.4+.